# javascript/jquery/mootools/other js lib- can i write text over a css3 gradient

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I have with me a script that generates gradients using CSS3.

I want to do 2 things with the gradient, either separately or together--

(a) Allow user to write some text over the gradient at location chosen by user (indicated using mouse cursor).

(b) Allow user to choose from a set of fonts to be used when writing the text- the font can be a custom font or from Google Web Fonts collection...

I plan to implement the above in a GWT application, so any kind of javascript , incl libraries like mootools/jquery are acceptable for this work for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript/jquery/mootools/other js lib- can i save a css3 gradient as a image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181142/javascript-jquery-mootools-other-js-lib-can-i-save-a-css3-gradient-as-a-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is simply, "Can I write text over a CSS3 Gradient," you're answer is Yes.

CSS Gradients, when used, act as a background to an element.

Having a gradient background on an element is no different than declaring the background-color red or white.